# Prestashop Currency size

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

Hello Guys im new to prestashop .
 i want to increase the size of the currency symbol.

I wrote a module to override Tools.php and tools.js and placed it modules directory under themes.
The file structure is as follows

```
Mymodule\
-->mymodule.php
-->override
----->classes
-------->Tools.php
----->js
-------->tools.js
```

i just copied both the file from there respective folders and added the following code

at Tools.php i added this line of code just before before if ($no_utf8)

```
$c_char = '<span>'.$c_char.'</span>';
```

at tools.js i added this line of code before if (currencyBlank > 0)

```
currencySign = '<span>' + currencySign + '</span>';
```

thanks for your time

with Regards
AB

Answer (score 0):

In override/classes/Tools.php file:

```
public static function displayPrice(...)
{
   $price = paret::displayPrice(...);
   // use regex to seperate number from currency sign
   return $price.'<small>'.$sign.'</small>';
}
```

To override tools.js formatCUrreny, you need to insert a script block or file on every page that has:

```
var fnDefaultFormatCurrency = window.formatCurrency;
window.formatCurrency = function(price, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank){

    var priceStr = fnDefaultFormatCurrency(price, currencyFormat, currencySign, currencyBlank),

    // use regex here again

    priceFinal = price +' <small>' + sing+ '</small>';

    return priceFinal;
}
```

I actually needed to make something smaller so I used `small` but you can use something else. Note: you will have to replace `.text()` to `.html()` in ajax function to display HTMl correctly

Comment: Hello sorry for the late reply. Where Should i change .text() to .html () can you be specific . and Thanks You for the reply ..

Comment: Try to insert the two overrides first, chaging text() to html() will be a later problem. Basically if you pass 20.00 <small>$</small> to .text() it will display this text with visible HTML (escaped).